# Why I can't do arithmetic operations in console input "cin"?

Tags: c++

I am a beginner to C++. I am having some trouble or doubt;
The thing is, I am giving an arithmetic operation such as 2+2 in user input `cin>>`. But in return it gives output of 2!

**Code:**

```
#include "iostream"
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int t;
    cin>>t;      // Here I Have Given 2+2
    cout<<t;     // Instead of giving 4; It is giving me 2
    return 0;
}
```

Is There any solution to this?
Please Help Me!

Comment: You're expecting too much from an input-output functionality. `cin >> t` only reads the first integer from the input stream, the interpretation is left to the rest of the code. And it's a bit less trivial task than it may seem (think of operation precedence and parentheses).

Comment: Well I am sorry to disappoint you, but cin is for input, not for calculation. If you want your program to solve arithmetic expressions written  to input by user, you need to make it parse them and then process operators and operands

Comment: If you really want to dive into this rabbit hole, you can check [shunting-yard algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm).

Comment: `cin` is not a general expression parser - it reads exactly that it is told (a single integral value in your case) and stops when it encounters something that cannot be read.   Given `2+2`, the first value `2` will be read to `t`, and the input `+2` will be left in the input stream, so the program can read it if designed.  If you want parsing to turn `2+2` into `4`, you need to implement logic that recognise the first value (`2`), recognize the operation (`+`), recognises the second `2`, then combines those three pieces to produce `4`.

Answer (score 2):

You declare t as an integer.
You give "2+2" in input. That is no int, that's a string and cin reads the first integer from the input.

```
cin>>t;
cout<<t+t;
```

This would print 4. But the point here is that you can't assign arithmetic operations to cin. You need to create them in the code.

Comment: Is there any other way to do this type of calculations from user input?

Comment: You mean other than "actually do math on the input"? No. C++ is not a general purpose calculator, but you can write one in C++.